# Why aren't the table data tags available in the soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am very new to python and am trying to build a simple webscraper for a client's website. I thought I had successfully downloaded the html soup but it doesn't contain any of the table tags or data. This is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

main_url = 'https://www.grainger.com/category/pipe-hose-tube-fittings/hose-products/hose-fittings-couplings/cam-groove-fittings-gaskets/metal-cam-groove-fittings/stainless-steel-cam-groove-fittings'

headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"}
res = requests.get(main_url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")


rows = soup.findAll("tr", {"class":"search-table-view__web-parent-table-row"})
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: first check if page doesn't use JavaScript to add items. `urllib`, `requests`, `BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScritp. And then you may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: I checked this page and it use javascript to add this table. Turn off JavaScript in browser and reload page to see what `urllib`, `requests` can get from server.

Comment: JavaScript gets this table as JSON from https://www.grainger.com/product/tableview/GRAINGER-APPROVED-Type-F-Stainless-Steel-Cam-WP11501162?breadcrumbCatId=1001429

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common problem: page uses JavaScript to add items but `urllib`, `requests`, `BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript.

You could use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) or you can try to find url used by JavaScript to read data from server.

I found url used by JavaScript to get data from server and I used it with `requests` and I get JSON data which can be convert to Python dictionary/list

There are many data in this dictionary and now problem is to find correct values.

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.grainger.com/product/tableview/GRAINGER-APPROVED-Type-F-Stainless-Steel-Cam-WP11501162?breadcrumbCatId=1001429'
r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
data = r.json()

for item in data['headers']:
    print(item['title'])

for item in data['records'][0]['children']:
    for x in item['techAttributes']:
        print(' >', x['name'], '=',  x['value'])
    print('---')
```

Result:

```
Coupling Size
Thread Size
Max. Working Pressure @ 70 F
Includes Locking Arm
Fitting Type
Item #
Price
 > Coupling Size = 1/2"
 > Thread Size = 1/2"-14
 > Max. Working Pressure @ 70 F = 150 psi
 > Includes Locking Arm = No
 > Fitting Type = MNPT
 > Item # = None
 > Price = None
---
 > Coupling Size = 3/4"
 > Thread Size = 3/4"-14
 > Max. Working Pressure @ 70 F = 150 psi
 > Includes Locking Arm = No
 > Fitting Type = MNPT
 > Item # = None
 > Price = None
---
 > Coupling Size = 1"
 > Thread Size = 1"-11-1/2
 > Max. Working Pressure @ 70 F = 250 psi
 > Includes Locking Arm = No
 > Fitting Type = MNPT
 > Item # = None
 > Price = None
---
 > Coupling Size = 1-1/4"
 > Thread Size = 1-1/4"-11-1/2
 > Max. Working Pressure @ 70 F = 250 psi
 > Includes Locking Arm = No
 > Fitting Type = MNPT
 > Item # = None
 > Price = None
---
 > Coupling Size = 1-1/2"
 > Thread Size = 1-1/2"-11-1/2
 > Max. Working Pressure @ 70 F = 250 psi
 > Includes Locking Arm = No
 > Fitting Type = MNPT
 > Item # = None
 > Price = None
---
 > Coupling Size = 2"
 > Thread Size = 2"-11-1/2
 > Max. Working Pressure @ 70 F = 250 psi
 > Includes Locking Arm = No
 > Fitting Type = MNPT
 > Item # = None
 > Price = None
---
 > Coupling Size = 2-1/2"
 > Thread Size = 2-1/2"-8
 > Max. Working Pressure @ 70 F = 225 psi
 > Includes Locking Arm = No
 > Fitting Type = MNPT
 > Item # = None
 > Price = None
---
 > Coupling Size = 3"
 > Thread Size = 3"-8
 > Max. Working Pressure @ 70 F = 200 psi
 > Includes Locking Arm = No
 > Fitting Type = MNPT
 > Item # = None
 > Price = None
---
 > Coupling Size = 4"
 > Thread Size = 4"-8
 > Max. Working Pressure @ 70 F = 100 psi
 > Includes Locking Arm = No
 > Fitting Type = MNPT
 > Item # = None
 > Price = None
---
 > Coupling Size = 5"
 > Thread Size = 5"-8
 > Max. Working Pressure @ 70 F = 75 psi
 > Includes Locking Arm = No
 > Fitting Type = MNPT
 > Item # = None
 > Price = None
---
 > Coupling Size = 6"
 > Thread Size = 6"-8
 > Max. Working Pressure @ 70 F = 75 psi
 > Includes Locking Arm = No
 > Fitting Type = MNPT
 > Item # = None
 > Price = None
---
```